# Laravel 5.4 route simplification

Tags: laravel-5, url-routing, nested-resources

I've been trying to find some documentation on how to accomplish the following, but it seems like maybe I'm not using the correct search terms.

I would like to implement some simplified routes in Laravel 5.4 by omitting the route name from the path – for example:

1. `/{page}` instead of `/pages/{page}`
2. `/profile` instead of `/users/{user}/edit`
3. `/{exam}/{question}` (or even `/exams/{exam}/{question}`) instead of `/exams/{exam}/questions/{question}`

**Example of current routes**

```
Route::resource('exams.questions', 'ExamQuestionController', ['only' => ['show']]);
// exams/{exam}/question/{question}
```

I know how to do this with route closures and one-off routes (e.g.: `Route::get...`) but is there a way to do this using `Route::resource`?

In `rails` the above could be accomplished with:

```
resources :exams, path: '', only: [:index, :show] do
  resources :question, path: '', only: [:show]
end

// /:exam_id/:id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I haven't yet found a way to accomplish my test cases using strictly `Route::resource`, here is what I implemented to accomplish what I was trying to do:

```
// For: `/{exam}/{question}`
Route::group(['as' => 'exams.', 'prefix' => '{exam}'], function() {
  Route::get('{question}', [
    'as'      => 'question.show',
    'uses'    => 'QuestionController@show'
  ]);
});

// For: `/exams/{exam}/{question}`
Route::group(['as' => 'exams.', 'prefix' => 'exams/{exam}'], function() {
  Route::get('{question}', [
    'as'      => 'question.show',
    'uses'    => 'QuestionController@show'
  ]);
});

// For: `/profile`
Route::get('profile', function() {
  $controller = resolve('App\Http\Controllers\UserController');
  return $controller->callAction('edit', $user = [ Auth::user() ]);
})->middleware('auth')->name('users.edit');

// For: `/{page}`
// -------------- 
// Note that the above `/profile` route must come before 
// this route if using both methods as this route
// will capture `/profile` as a `{page}` otherwise
Route::get('{page}', [
  'as'      => 'page.show',
  'uses'    => 'PageController@show'
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot *and should not* be trying to do this with `Route::resource`.

The whole purpose of `Route::resource` is that it creates the routes in a specific way that matches the common "RESTful Routing" pattern.

There is nothing wrong with wanting simpler routes (no one is forcing you to use RESTful routing), but you will need to make them yourself with `Route::get`, etc. as you already know.

From [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#resource-controllers) (not exactly your case, but related to it - showing that `Route::resource` is not meant to be super-configurable):

> #### Supplementing Resource Controllers
>
> If you need to add additional routes to a resource controller beyond the default set of resource routes, you should define those routes before your call to Route::resource; otherwise, the routes defined by the resource method may unintentionally take precedence over your supplemental routes:
>
> ```
> Route::get('photos/popular', 'PhotoController@method');
>
> Route::resource('photos', 'PhotoController');
> ```